# Publicly available transaction data

Tags: data-request, data.gov, big-data

I need publicly available *transaction* data to use for my statistical analysis project.

Preferably, it should relate to either:

- Flight data (arrival, departure, number of seats, locations, etc.)
- Sales data
- Medical data

Comment: Can you expand your question a little? What do you consider *transaction data*? It's unclear what that would mean for e.g. the category medical data, and even the examples you give for flight data don't look very 'transactional' to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two sales data sets from Kaggle:

- [Rossmann Store Sales](https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/data)
- [Walmart Recruiting — Store Sales Forecasting](https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting/data)

You can ask on the forums to get an answer for the dateset licenses from the competition admins.

Comment: By default you may only use kaggle data for the specific competition it is linked to, and only while the competition is active, it may not be used for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

For free sales data, check out this database on Quandl:

**US Census Bureau**  - Here are the datasets you'll see if you search for "sales" within this database:

https://www.quandl.com/data/USCENSUS-U-S-Census-Bureau?keyword=sales

(Disclosure: I work for Quandl)